# entry in AndroidManifest that would limit app to ARMv7 devices only?

Tags: android, android-manifest, armv7

Is there a setting I can manually put into my AndroidManifest.XML that would limit the devices on which the app can be installed to ARMv7 architecture only?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an app to Google Play, if you are using the NDK and only include an armeabi-v7a binary, it will be visible to devices with the ARMv7 arch.

Comment: Thank you Laurence, but I was thinking more of Samsung and TStore markets. On Samsung, I have to go and check every freaking one of the 70+ devices they have available to see whether one is ARMv6 or not and exclude it. And on TStore they don't even give you the option of excluding devices manually, but apparently take the limitations straight out of AndroidManifest (and in my case are not doing it "correctly" since the app is done with Corona SDK, which only makes an ARMv7 binary, and they still show all devices available).

Comment: Aha. You could always call System.getProperty("os.arch") on startup to double check. But thats less than ideal

Comment: Yes I would say it is less than ideal :) Since I could only do that *after* install, and the app actually refuses to install (or crashes on starting up, I am not sure).

Comment: Is compiling for other architectures not a viable option?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Corona SDK, though a pleasure to work with in all kinds of ways, if very inflexible in this respect.